# Crawl and Concatenate in Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm trying to crawl movie list with Scrapy (I take only the Director & Movie title fields).
Sometimes, there are two directors and Scrapy scape them as different. So the first director will be alon the movie title but for the second there will be no movie title.

So I created a condition like this :

```
if director2:
            item['director'] = map(unicode.strip,titres.xpath("tbody/tr/td/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/h2/div/a/text()").extract())
```

The last div[2] exists only if there are two directors.

And I wanted to concatenate like this : director1, director2

Here is my full code :

```
class movies(scrapy.Spider):
name ="movielist"
allowed_domains = ["domain.com"]
start_urls = ["http://www.domain.com/list"]

def parse(self, response):
    for titles in response.xpath('//*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " grid")]'):
        item = MovieItem()
        director2 = Selector(text=html_content).xpath("h2/div[2]/a/text()")
        if director2:
            item['director'] = map(unicode.strip,titres.xpath,string-join("h2//concat(div[1]/a/text(), ".", div[2]/a/text())").extract())
        else:
            item['director'] = map(unicode.strip,titres.xpath("h2/div/a/text()").extract())
            item['director'] = map(unicode.strip,titres.xpath,string-join("h2//concat(div[1]/a/text(), ".", div[2]/a/text())").extract())
            item['title'] = map(unicode.strip,titres.xpath("h2/a/text()").extract())
        yield item
```

Sample HTML with one director:

```
<h2>
    <a href="#">Movie's title</a>
    <div>Info</div>
    <div><a href="#">Director's name</a></div>
</h2>
```

Sometime, when there are two directors :

```
<h2>
    <a href="#">Movie's title</a>
    <div>Info</div>
    <div><a href="#">Director's name</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">Second director's name</a></div>
</h2>
```

Can you tell me what's wrong with my syntax ?

I tested without the condition and withtout the concatenation and it works very well.

This is my first time with Python so please be indulgent.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please add sample HTML input, it's quite hard to imagine the content by reverse thinking your XPath

Comment: @paultrmbrth Oh sorry, I added a sample HTML input and I reduced my xpath just for the example because my real problem lies in the syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get all the directors (1, 2 or more) and join them with `join()`:

```
item['director'] = ", ".join(titles.xpath("h2/div/a/text()").extract())
```

A better Scrapy-specific approach though would be to use an [`ItemLoader`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) and [`Join()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#scrapy.contrib.loader.processor.Join) processor. Define an `ItemLoader`:

```
from scrapy.contrib.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import TakeFirst, MapCompose, Join

class MovieLoader(ItemLoader):

    default_output_processor = TakeFirst()

    director_in = MapCompose(unicode.strip)
    director_out = Join()
```

And let it worry about stripping and joining:

```
loader = MovieLoader(MovieItem(), titles)
...
loader.add_xpath("director", "h2/div/a/text()")
```

Comment: This is a perfect approach. Thank you Sir !