# How to extract all text from a div including text from siblings with Scrapy and Xpah?

Tags: xpath, scrapy

While extracting text from a remote URL with scrapy 2.4 I found that  does only return the text within this div, not within it's child nodes.

E.g.

```
<div>
    text
    <p>text inside child</p>
    <h2>bla</h2>
    more text
</div>
```

This only returns two array elments 'text' and 'more text'.

```
all_text = response.xpath('/div/text()').extract()
```

I would need to extract the entire text within this div including text from all child nodes merged into one non formated string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

`/div//text()`

So that you get any nested text into inner elements.

Comment: Interesting approach! Thank you that worked. Do you know how to join the .extract() into one single string? I guess I have to itterate over each element (theirby striping each one)

Comment: use `join()` method, there's an example in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29434591/crawl-and-concatenate-in-scrapy).

Comment: Nice! Thank you.