# Not able to find the Xpath

Tags: web-scraping, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape IMDB top 250 movies using scrapy and stuck in finding the xpath for duration[**I need to extract "2","h","44" and "m"**] of each movie. Website link : https://www.imdb.com/title/tt15097216/?ref_=adv_li_tt

Here's the image of the HTML:
[image: Image of the HTML]

I've tried this Xpath but it's not accurate:

```html
//li[@class ='ipc-inline-list__item']/following::li/text()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's always in the same position, what about:

```
//li[@class ='ipc-inline-list__item']/following::li[2]
```

or more simply:

```
//li[@class ='ipc-inline-list__item'][3]
```

or since the others have hyperlinks as the child, filter to just the `li` that has `text()` child nodes:

```
//li[@class ='ipc-inline-list__item'][text()]
```

However, the original XPath may be fine - it may be how you are consuming the information. If you are using `.get()` then try `.getAll()` instead.

Comment: It's not scraping the desired duration(2h44m). Is there any way to select the underlying strings inside the <li> tag?

Comment: after addressing the items, are you using `.get()` or `.getAll()`? Your original selector asking for `text()` may be fine, maybe you are using `.get()` which will only return 1 item and should instead be using `.getAll()`?

Comment: I've included getall() and now it works. Thank you sir. How can I concat the obtained strings?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29436081/14419

Comment: I am a beginner in this web scraping and stack overflow. Thanks for helping me out, sir.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this XPath to locate the element:

```
//span[contains(@class,'Runtime')]
```

To extract the text you can use this:

```
//span[contains(@class,'Runtime')]/text()
```

Comment: I want to locate the runtime of the movie(2h44m) and not the runtime of the trailer. Using this Xpath I can only able to select 2 and not the rest. ```//li[@class ='ipc-inline-list__item'][3]```